# Is there a heuristic argument for the expression $ \textbf{g} = \frac {\mathbf{S}}{c^2}$?

Tags: electromagnetism, momentum, classical-electrodynamics, poynting-vector

[Electromagnetic momentum density](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Momentum#Classical_electromagnetism) and the [Poynting vector](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Poynting_vector) are related by the simple expression:
$$ \textbf{g} = \frac {\mathbf{S}}{c^2}$$

It can be rigorously derived from Maxwell's equations, but is there a more heuristic derivation?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Light follows null geodesics, which means that they have no rest mass.  Given the relativistic formula $m^{2}c^{4} = E^{2} - p^{2}c^{2}$, the result follows